# Having trouble drawing lines in d3js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, path

First time d3.js user, new to javascript as well.  I want to create a chart that plots 3 waves, the third of which being the partial deconstruction of the first 2.  I've saved the calculations that I need into a JSON object called data and I have created the 3 lines `line1` `line2` and `line3`.  I have followed youtube tutorials and looked at countless code snippets on stackoverflow and Mike Bostock's wikipedia page.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why the lines aren't drawing?  I'm new to JSON but I wanted to learn it so that's how I saved my data.  Am I not binding the data properly?  The console doesn't give me an error when I run the code but I noticed that the path contains NAN or not a number values for what appears to be the `time` member of the JSON object:  `d="M0,NaNL1.8,NaNL3.6,NaNL5.4,NaNL7.2,NaNL9,NaNL10.8,NaNL12.600000000000001,NaNL14.4,NaNL16.200000000000003,NaNL18.000000000000004,NaNL19.800000000000004,NaNL21.600000000000005,NaNL23.400000000000006,NaNL25.200000000000006,NaNL27.000000000000007,NaNL28.800000000000008,NaNL30.60000000000001,NaNL32.40000000000001,NaNL34.20000000000001,NaNL36.00000000000001,NaNL37.800000000000004,NaNL39.599999999999994,NaNL41.4,NaNL43.199999999999996,NaNL44.99999999999999` and it goes on and on.  I'm assuming these are my values that I'm generating in my first loop?

Part of code that might be giving issues (full code available below in jsfiddle link):

```
    var line1 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return widthScale(d.time); })
    .y(function(d) { return verticalScale(d.y1); });

var line2 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return widthScale(d.time); })
    .y(function(d) { return verticalScale(d.y2); });

var line3 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return widthScale(d.time); })
    .y(function(d) { return verticalScale(d.y3); });

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.time = + d.time;
    d.wave1 = d.wave1;
    d.wave2 = d.wave2;
    d.wave3 = d.wave3;
});
```

and maybe this:

```
    // draw lines? what am I missing?
canvas.append("g")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line1);
```

Any help is appreciated, and I will be happy to provide any additional information.  Thank you!

This is the jsfiddle of my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/fdhnqh1d/3/

Comment: Please post the part of the code that you need help with.  You have provided some output, but we cant debug that.

Comment: Ok i edited where I think the problems might lie and the full code is available in the jsfiddle at the bottom. Thanks for taking a look

Comment: Thanks. I missed your reference to the fiddle because tunnel vision sees that there is no code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fdhnqh1d/4/ to fix the generation.

Your line generators were referencing an undefined property `d.y1`. Here I changed to `d.wave1` to match your data model.

```
var line1 = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return widthScale(d.time); })
.y(function(d) { return verticalScale(d.wave1); });
```

Now it outputs

```
M0,263.5596698504196L1.8,263.5674382668522L3.6,263.5751378843530...
```

Comment: Beautiful! That issue is taken care of now.  However, I'm still confused about why my `line1` isn't getting drawn though?  I see when I inspect the svg element that a path called `line1` is being placed, but the line doesn't actually appear.  I must be drawing it wrong somehow.

Comment: First thing I would check is if it is positioned or oriented in the place you expect. It might need translation.

Comment: Checked that, it doesn't need a translation and the issue isn't that the line is invisible. The line is getting drawn but when I inspect it, it reveals that it is 0x0 pixels. So it starts the line but never adds the first point.